# Filling a vector of strings

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I'm trying to fill a vector of strings using the default "fill" constructor of the STL vector.  However, I'm getting the error message below:

```
10:55: error: conversion from ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >*’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >’ requested
```

Here is the source code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string x = "abcd";
    vector< string > stv = new vector< string > (10, x);
    for ( int i = 0; i < stv.size(); i++) {
        cout << stv[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `operator new` returns a pointer, and you shouldn't be using `new` here in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are using `new` unnecessarily. Really you should be using the constructor directly instead of doing assignment.

```
std::vector<std::string> stv(10, x);
```

The way you have it, you would need to do this:

```
std::vector<std::string> *stv = new std::vector<std::string>(10, x);

for ( int i = 0; i < stv->size(); i++) {
    cout << (*stv)[i] << endl;
}
```

Also, rather than doing `string x = "abcd";`, do `string x("abcd");`. The first one will create an empty string object using the default constructor, and then call `operator=` to set the string contents, whereas the second will use the constructor to build it from a `char*` will is more efficient. This is the same reason you wouldn't do this:

```
std::vector<std::string> stv = std::vector<std::string>(10, x);
```

That would create two vectors, and then copy all 10 elements from the second one into the first, and then discard the second one, duing lots of extra work. This now less of an issue in C++11 due to move semantics though.

Answer (score 1):

Main issue is that `stv` is not a pointer you don't need to new to allocate dynamic it, could be fixed like this:

```
std::vector< std::string > stv(10, x);
```

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> stv(10, x);`

Comment: @EdS. good point, thanks, updated it.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign a pointer to std::vector to a std::vector.

You could either use the std::vector constructor directly:

```
std::vector<std::string>    stv(10, x);
```

Or you could use a pointer to std::vector:

```
std::vector<std::string>*   stv = new std::vector<std::string>(10, x)
```

Good luck